# Generate json to php find ID value through php

Tags: php

Find ID value through php

```
stdClass Object ( [Providers] => Array ( 
            [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                [Main_Fax] => 
                [Signed_POA] => No 
                [Signed_HIPAA] => No 
                [Website] => www.google.com 
                [VAR_Provider_Type] => Template Test 
                [State_Temp] => 
                [City] => 
                [Notes] => 
                [Main_Phone] => 
                [ZIP] => 
                [Provider_Type_Temp] => 
                [State] => Alaska 
                [Signed_Purchae_Agreement] => No 
                [Reimbursement_Rate] => 0 
                [ID] => 977948000009029003 
                [Provider_Name] => Amit 
                [Address_Line_1] => 
                [In_Network] => No 
                [Address_Line_2] => 
            ) 
        ) 
    )
```

Seprate this json & show id value through php -> means this value [ID] => 977948000009029003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let your array is `$arr`.

Now try this:

```
$arr->Providers[0]->ID;
```

**Result:**

> 977948000009029003

Answer (score 2):

```
$data->Providers[0]->ID
```

See the structure of the object you gave us. You can see there's an object with a item called `Providers`. You can then see that the value of "Providers" is an array indexed by a integer, which inside it has an Object. The object contains the ID you wish to obtain.

Object > Array > Object